# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: When trying to 'pip install quantum-grove' in window

Tags: python, pip, compiler-errors, anaconda, grove

I'm trying to fix with '`pip install --upgrade setuptools && python -m pip install --upgrade pip`', but it still not work and error. How can I do?

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
> 'c:\users\it\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys,
> setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\it\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g2ejs5st\immutables_17746a89c66b4c4daeb1c8eee86da7de\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\it\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g2ejs5st\immutables_17746a89c66b4c4daeb1c8eee86da7de\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\it\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-69foxfyt'
> cwd: C:\Users\it\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g2ejs5st\immutables_17746a89c66b4c4daeb1c8eee86da7de
> Complete output (21 lines):

This is text that come from error.

Comment: It looks like `pip` is attempting to compile the module from source. Though it's impossible to be sure, because your question ends with "Complete output (21 lines):" and you omitted those 21 lines from your question. Compiling from source is not always straightforward on Windows. Also, you need prerequisites. The docs for quantum-grove say: For Windows users: Both qutip and cvxpy are fairly tricky to install under windows and we therefore recommend using Anaconda's conda package manager to install these first and then pip to install quantum-grove. Have you done that?

Answer (score 1):

Good evening, thank you for everyone's answers. I already fixed the problem. I noticed in the text of an error it shows 'error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": [https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/'](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/%27)
So I got into the link and install C++ build tools then it works!! It is my fault to overlook a shown error text. Thank you again.